# Why do long well thought out answers result in negative reputation while short snappy ones get all the rep?

Tags: discussion

It seems some long well thought out answers receive a very low vote count:

[Better way to do this LINQ to XML query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873037)

On the other hand, here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471940

Jeff's witty, and grossly incorrect comment got him <s>66</s>104 upvotes, for a response that probably took him 5 seconds to come up with.

Should I not bother answering complex questions which require lots of work to answer?

Why do long well thought out answers result in negative reputation while short snappy ones get all the rep?

**EDIT:**

So people do not think I am singling out Jeff, here is a bigger list:

- Is it wrong to go to interviews while employed?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205003  306 135
- What's the difference between JavaScript and Java?   [What's the difference between JavaScript and Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062)  144 108
- How do I move the turtle in LOGO?    [How do I move the turtle in LOGO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003841) 196 102
- How to check if a number is a power of 2 [How to check if a number is a power of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600293)  446 97
- How do I calculate someone's age in C#?  [Calculate age in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9)   480 89
- I don't like this... Is this cheating the language?  [I don't like this... Is this cheating the language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836945)  370 81
- Why do some websites add "Slugs" to the end of URLs? [Why do some websites add "Slugs" to the end of URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47427)   372 70
- Why do people have trouble learning recursion?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230218  428 68
- What's the difference between JavaScript and Java?   [What's the difference between JavaScript and Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062)  400 65
- Why Windows 7 isn't written in C#?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783238  162 65
- Why does every man and his dog want to code a blogging engine?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471940  140 63
- What annoys you as a programmer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27347   124 56
- Do you use "kibibyte" as a unit of measurement in your programs? [Do you use "kibibyte" as a unit of measurement in your programs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176922)  66  56
- The Programmer's Bill of Rights  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100518  472 54
- Big-O for Eight Year Olds?   [Big-O for Eight Year Olds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107165)  452 54
- Can you code while drunk?    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193551  254 52
- Do you prefer "if (var)" or "if (var != 0)"? [Do you prefer "if (var)" or "if (var != 0)"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404838)  368 50
- What is the opposite of 'parse'? [What is the opposite of 'parse'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148857)  94  49
- Database-wide unique-yet-simple identifiers in SQL Server    [Database-wide unique-yet-simple identifiers in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721497)  486 48
- How many lines of code is too many?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20981   164 48

Query:

```
select top 20 ' - ' + q.Title ,'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/' + cast(q.Id as varchar(max)) , datalength(a.Body),
    cast(a.Score as varchar) From Answers a 
join Questions q on a.ParentId = q.Id and q.IsWiki = 0
where datalength(a.Body) < 500
order by a.Score desc
```

And for even more enjoyment, here is a list of Marc's longest 20 answers, the most votes he got from a long answer is 9 next up is 4, but the avg is probably around 2.

- Deserialization Error: The XML element 'name' from namespace '' is already present in the current scope. [Deserialization Error: The XML element 'name' from namespace '' is already present in the current scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523245)  13466   2
- Data binding dynamic data    [Data binding dynamic data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882214)  11614   2
- How do you implement Pipes and Filters pattern with LinqToSQL/Entity Framework/NHibernate?   [How do you implement Pipes and Filters pattern with LinqToSQL/Entity Framework/NHibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679027)  11456   3
- What's the way to implement Save / Load functionality?   [What's the way to implement Save / Load functionality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348022)  10818   4
- Wait for pooled threads to complete. [Wait for pooled threads to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540078)  10754   1
- How can I write a generic container class that implements a given interface in C#?   [How can I write a generic container class that implements a given interface in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847809)  10570   9
- TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(thisType) to return properties, which are write-only    [TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(thisType) to return properties, which are write-only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772107)  9976    3
- C#/winforms: how to best bind a propertygrid and a System.Data.DataRow   [C#/winforms: how to best bind a propertygrid and a System.Data.DataRow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943621)  9878    1
- How can I add my attributes to Code-Generated Linq2Sql classes properties?   [How can I add my attributes to Code-Generated Linq2Sql classes properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393687)  9456    1
- Why does WPF support binding to properties of an object, but not fields? [Why does WPF support binding to properties of an object, but not fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842575)  8552    1
- Using the .NET collection editor without using a property grid control   [Using the .NET collection editor without using a property grid control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473506)  8244    3
- Expose a collection of enums (flags) in Visual Studio designer   [Expose a collection of enums (flags) in Visual Studio designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831612)  7598    1
- Delphi to .NET + C#  [Delphi to .NET + C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237715)  7526    3
- MonthCalendar.SelectionRange databinding example [MonthCalendar.SelectionRange databinding example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377163)  7516    1
- .Net Property Grid. Is there a way to let the Grid manipulate object in different way    [.Net Property Grid. Is there a way to let the Grid manipulate object in different way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931644)  7372    2
- In LINQ to SQL, how do you pass pass parts of a LINQ query into a function   [In LINQ to SQL, how do you pass parts of a LINQ query into a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434480)  7180    4
- DataGridView Binding [DataGridView Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634643)  6994    3
- String.Join vs. StringBuilder: which is faster?  [String.Join vs. StringBuilder: which is faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585860)  6834    4
- LINQ to SQL query against a list of entities [LINQ to SQL query against a list of entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729899)  6746    3
- Better way to do this LINQ to XML query? [Better way to do this LINQ to XML query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873037)  6728    1

Query:

```
select top 20 ' - ' + q.Title ,'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/' + cast(q.Id as varchar(max)) , datalength(a.Body),
    cast(a.Score as varchar) From Answers a 
join Questions q on a.ParentId = q.Id and q.IsWiki = 0
where a.OwnerUserId = 23354
order by datalength(a.Body) desc
```

Comment: Instead of lists of data, can you perhaps create a graph of the length of answers vs. average score? Maybe we can find the optimum length for maximum rep...

Comment: Thanks for digging out the list; I can now answer your question just from one of the comments: "Wow. Marc - I really appreciate you taking the time to do this.". Admittedly, this type of response is rare...

Comment: lol; I notice you're now at +2; obviously the more discerning folks here at MSO agree that the answer isn't pants... simply, it didn't get spotted at the time.

Comment: -1 may only be the result of a single eejit's vote.

Comment: @Tom, yes, I think that was the only attention that question ever got ... till now

Comment: Is there somewhere on the internet where we can post these queries, and get the data?

Comment: While this discussion is valid, I still think it's a little shady, because any of use could post our downvoted answers, and the community of MSO would upvote us.

Comment: @devin, I removed my post, so the discussion can remain unhindered

Comment: Jeff's "answer" should have been a comment... Miss-using his own system :-)

Comment: Looking at some of the question titles, they _scream_ for a witty rebuttal ("What is the difference between Java and JavaScript", come on, have you even _looked_ at the languages?!; "Why isn't Windows written in C#", when Windows _much_ predates C#)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think its only fair I answer this question:

As a trend short answers **do not** have an edge over long answer, in fact long answers in general get up to a 6x edge over one liners. This edge is much reduced for the more complicated tags such as 'multithreading' where you only get a 3x edge (and you reach the optimum length earlier). This also explains why Marc's long answers are so poorly voted on. Few people understand them hence the low vote count.

At some point you stop getting an edge and start losing it. This usually happens around the 15k letter mark, anything longer than that loses the edge.

I guess **anyone** can find the edge cases, but edge cases do not prove a point. I also think its hard to make a point that rules need to change just to accommodate for edge cases.

So to answer my original questions:

> Why do long well thought out answers
>   result in negative reputation while
>   short snappy ones get all the rep?

Well the data does not back that up. It just backs up that there are edge cases where this happens.

> Should I not bother answering complex
>   questions involving concurrency
>   anymore?

**If** all you are interested in is rep, concurrency is a very poor tag to be participating in.

> What do I suggest SO does?

Move along, nothing to see here. I guess. It's the way the system works. Reputation is not a measure of effort or correctness, its a measure of popularity.

Comment: Yup.             ;-)

Answer (score 12):

I guess...

In part, because more people understand them.

In part, because more people see them (before the question is marked as complete).

I agree that the java/javascript one is... unduly upvoted. There are other examples of this, but I can't think of a way to handle it, except perhaps Jon Skeet's suggestion of a rep cap **per question** (rather than per day) - so (for example) you only see rep for the first 10 (pick a number...) upvotes (100 points).

I've got some similar answers; for example some things relating to obscure and complex uses of `System.ComponentModel` - where a *short* (minimal) example is a few hundred lines of code. It is probably only going to get appreciated by the OP; but that is fine. The answer is still good, and I'm proud of it. Like you should be of the detail in your answer.

Comment: I guess, the second part of the question is, what should motivate me to answer questions like the one I linked, it took me a non-trivial amount of time to answer, I even wrote code to explain the comments.

Comment: +1 @Marc, completely agree. @Sam, I think that if you're passionate about a topic and it interests you then you should at least get some satisfaction in the answer you provided. I agree that some questions/tags are especially biased to huge amounts of up votes with no effort, but I can't think of any ways to fix this. If you spend a lot of time on complex answers you're probably going to have to settle with self growth as a reward.

Comment: @Marc, I provided 20 examples for your enjoyment, I can make the list longer if you wish. Instead of looking bitter and getting all pissed off at Greg, I changed the example to point to Jeff :p

Comment: @Marc, for your added enjoyment I put a list of your longest answers for comparison. See amended question.

Answer (score 6):

People read answers with length proportional to their attention span.

Answer (score 5):

> Why do long well thought out answers result in negative reputation while short snappy ones get all the rep?

Two data points isn't really enough. [There are long, well thought out answers that get plenty of up-votes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448673/how-do-emulators-work-and-how-are-they-written/448689#448689). Just not yours.

---

**Edit:** a few stats pulled from the June data dump...

Average length of answers with a score of 30 or greater: **1060 characters**
Average length of answers with a score of 0 or less: **700 characters**
Average score of answers with a length of 5000 characters or more: **6**
Average score of answers with a length of 300 characters or less: **2**

Comment: @Shog, there are also plenty of opposite examples, see my amended question

Comment: @Shog, now you have 20 data points (see amended question) :) agree its not enough, but there is a pattern here.

Comment: @Sam: the 20 lowest-ranked answers include some very short ones as well (although there does appear to be greater variation - some > 1000 chars, some less than 100). I've added some stats to my question; suffice to say, i don't think your premise is valid.

Comment: @Shog, you have to exclude the community wiki questions to get valid stats (also analysis per tag is kind of important). The real numbers seem much lower. I get a sweet spot around the 15K mark, and then the amount of avg votes decreases. As a rule having a longer answer gives you an edge to a point. But there is only about a 6x difference between really long answers and one liners. And really long answers take a whole lot more effort.

Comment: Well, i was hoping to goad you into doing some better analysis to back up your claim... but i guess i'm mistaken as to what that even was. I thought you were upset that long answers got down-voted while short ones got all the rep; instead, it seems you feel that long answers should have a much bigger edge due to the time it takes to write them. Heh... Perhaps SO could implement an "A for Effort" badge to reward those who write long, low-scoring posts?

Comment: :) "A for Effort badge" nice one. You know you are right, its the edge cases that really bother me. As a trend I agree that stuff is kind of OK as it is. looking only at the multithreading tag, the really long answers get only a x2.5 edge, which kind of makes sense since its just too hard for people to grasp.

Comment: @shog, I gave a shot at answering this, see my answer

Answer (score 5):

People vote for what they understand and I think it's not that people don't appreciate that answer of yours, they simply don't understand it. And yes attention span does come into it.

There's also something to be said for being pithy. Greg's answer is basically a repeat of something said elsewhere (as far as I know). And "Java is to JavaScript what Car is to Carpet" is a succinct and correct answer to the question ie there is no relationship other than sharing some common letters.

As for long answers not getting upvoted, I just had a look and my top 7 voted answers are all quite long. IMHO there is a skill to writing a long answer effectively (well, writing *any* answer effectively).

Just because something is long doesn't mean it's a good answer (both in terms of content as well as the ability for others to digest it) and just because another answer is shorter doesn't necessarily mean that other answer is worse.

Comment: I take the pithy: My big question is this: "Should I not bother answering complex questions involving concurrency anymore?" I do need to do analyze that particular tag and look for max upvotes and look at all the answers, my gut is telling me that it is a problem area in SO.

Comment: I think sometimes software developers half-expect human beings to act like computer code...in a reasonable, logical way. I agree that you put alot of effort into what is probably a very good answer and if a computer algorithm was marking it, you would probably get top marks. But we are dealing with people here, not computer code...the kind of people (no offence intended to anyone) who vote politicians into office based on news media sound bites. SO is full of people - not much you can do about it, I'm afraid

Comment: @Cletus, I removed Greg from my examples, and put Jeff there instead ...

Comment: @Cletus, how many of your long answers involve code samples? I think having source code in your answer is key to not receiving upvotes, if Marc's list is anything to go by.

Comment: This one got 33 upvotes and is code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/474535/best-way-to-represent-a-fraction-in-java/474577#474577

Answer (score 4):

I suspect the problem is that it's difficult to tell whether or not your answer is correct. As someone that doesn't understand a lick of C# I have no idea if your answer is brilliant or horribly wrong. So I don't vote.

Greg's answer, on the other hand, is both witty and common knowledge, and therefore gets upvoted a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Short attention spans.

(sorry for the long sentence)

Comment: tl;              dr

Answer (score 2):

We prefer short witty technically correct quips to long-winded, boring answers. We are busy and have ADD. I bet that on weekends longer answers receive more upvotes.